# SQL Server - Select one random record not showing duplicates

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have two tables, events and photos, which relate together via the 'Event_ID' column. I wish to select ONE random photo from each event and display them.

How can I do this?

I have the following which displays all the photos which are associated. How can I limit it to one per event?

```
SELECT Photos.Photo_Id, Photos.Photo_Path, Photos.Event_Id, Events.Event_Title,
   Events.Event_StartDate, Events.Event_EndDate FROM Photos, Events 
WHERE 
   Photos.Event_Id = Events.Event_Id AND 
   Events.Event_EndDate < GETDATE() AND 
   Events.Event_EndDate IS NOT NULL AND
   Events.Event_StartDate IS NOT NULL
ORDER BY NEWID()
```

Thanks

Luke Stratton

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could use a `cross apply` to retrieve one random photo per event:

```
select *
from Events
cross apply (
    select top 1 *
    from Photos
    where Photos.Event_Id = Events.Event_Id
    order by newid()
) RandomPhoto
where Events.Event_EndDate < GETDATE()
and Events.Event_EndDate IS NOT NULL
and Events.Event_StartDate IS NOT NULL
```

Use an `outer apply` if you'd like to retrieve events without any photos.

Answer (score 0):

Look at [this xaprb article](http://www.xaprb.com/blog/2006/12/07/how-to-select-the-firstleastmax-row-per-group-in-sql/). It shows several techniques you could use. It recommends a minimal-row and self-join approach.